# How to rotate a compass after the last one is finished?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am making a compass which rotates every 5 degree, but the problem is when the user rotate the device more than 5 degree i get several responses in the same time, and the method that rotate the device will be called several times, before the last one will finish, so it doesn't give a smooth way to the compass. How can i rotate the compass after the last one is finished?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) {
       /* Rotate the compass to the selected degree */
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
           [self.compassImageView rotateByDegree:degree clockWise:YES];
       }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
//    [manager stopUpdatingHeading];

    double rotation = newHeading.magneticHeading * 3.14159 / 180;

    [_compass_image setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotation)];

}
```